# Securing SharePoint Autohosted Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-addin

I am creating an autohosted SharePoint app.
There are tons of really good articles out there that explains how to get started.

Unfortunately, I haven't find any article/tutorial yet which explains how to secure the actual Azure hosted app.

Basically, I have created an ASP .Net MVC 4 based autohosted app.
To start with, the Web project has the **Anonymous Authentication** enabled.
Due to this, anyone who knows the ***.o365apps.net** url of the app can access the app functionality.

But, I would only like to allow the users registered in our Office 365 SharePoint site to have access of the app.

It would be really great to redirect users to O365 site to log-in and then redirect them back to the app. What would be the best way to achieve this functionality?

I would really appreciate if you can please point me to the right direction :)